# Which web part properties can / cannot be edited using CSOM?

Tags: web-part, client-object-model

For a Content Editor Web Part for example it seems we can update Width but not Content:

```
webPart.Properties["Width"] = "100px";
webPartDefinition.SaveWebPartChanges();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); // Works

webPart.Properties["Content"] = "CEWP Content";
webPartDefinition.SaveWebPartChanges();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); // throws "The Content property does not exist"
```

Can we only update some common web part properties?

(web service support seems quite bad: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvcwebpartpages.webpartpageswebservice.savewebpart(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I know you have CSOM here, but you don't have an answer yet so I thought I'd try to help where I can. The code below is JSOM. There may be similar functionality on the C# side of the house. Hopefully this provides at least some help. As far as what you can/cannot edit the way you are trying, I would think it is the common elements such as those found in the UI menu when you edit web part properties.

```
var oPage = web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(url);
var oLimitedWebPartManager = oPage.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
var oWebPartXml = '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>' +
  '<WebPart xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"' +
  ' xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"' +
  ' xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2\">' +
  '<Title>' + title + '</Title><FrameType>Default</FrameType>' +
  '<Description>' + description + '</Description>' +
  '<IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded><ZoneID></ZoneID><PartOrder></PartOrder>' +
  '<FrameState>Normal</FrameState><Height /><Width /><AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>' +
  '<AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange><AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>' +
  '<AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect><AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>' +
  '<AllowHide>true</AllowHide><IsVisible>false</IsVisible><DetailLink /><HelpLink />' +
  '<HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode><Dir>Default</Dir><PartImageSmall />' +
  '<MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>' +
  '<PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge><IsIncludedFilter />' +
  '<Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, ' +
  'PublicKeyToken=94de0004b6e3fcc5</Assembly>' +
  '<TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>' +
  '<ContentLink xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\" >' + link + '</ContentLink>' +
  '<Content xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\">' +
  '<![CDATA[' + cdata + ']]></Content>' +
  '<PartStorage xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\" /></WebPart>';

var oWebPartDefinition = oLimitedWebPartManager.importWebPart(oWebPartXml);
var oWebpart = webPartDefinition.get_webPart();
oLimitedWebPartManager.addWebPart(oWebpart, webpartZone, webpartIndex);
context.load(oWebpart);
```