# Get inner content of Content editor web part Programatically using CSOM C#

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online, client-object-model, content-editor-web-part

I need to Access Web parts **Content** Property but it is not available in Web Part Properties when I tried with Client side object model C#.

Please find below reference links for detail information.

[Which web part properties can / cannot be edited using CSOM?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92519/which-web-part-properties-can-cannot-be-edited-using-csom)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539301(v=office.14).aspx

http://wendellj.blogspot.in/2012/03/c-add-content-editor-web-part.html

I am able to getTitle of web Part but I need the content

Comment: Have you tried requesting the page by creating a `HttpWebRequest` and then read the HTML from the response?

Comment: its a simple web application just try to access all web parts of current page , able to access list and libraries added as a web part in page, but when try to get content editor properties unable to get content property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSOM `LimitedWebPartManager` only allows import of a web part, but not export. So no, you cannot access the `Content` property.

There is an Office UserVoice suggestion to introduce this CSOM capability: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/6413925-expose-microsoft-sharepoint-webpartpages-splimited

As an alternative for now, you may use the `GetWebPart2` method of the  `WebPartPagesWebService` to get the content: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979489(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If this helps someone else,

```
using(ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("siteURL")) {  
  SecureString password = new SecureString();
  ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("onlineEmail", password);
  File file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/pages/default.aspx");
  LimitedWebPartManager wpManager = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
  Guid wpID= new Guid("{GUID}");
  ClientResult<string> wpXml= wpManager.ExportWebPart(wpID);
  ctx.ExecuteQuery();

  //Parse wpXml.Value to get Content Element
}
```